# How can I use the PowerShell command "Get-AdminPowerAppsUserDetails" for ALL the users

Tags: powershell, powerapps

I need to get (in PowerShell) the las time a user used a PowerApp.
I can get that information from the command **Get-AdminPowerAppsUserDetails**, but that command gives you the data of **only one** user, and the output is only directed to a file (that´s the way the command works).
So If I want the data of all the users in the tenant, I need to create a loop through the users list, call that command for every user, and **I must create an output file for every user**. Finally I have to concatenate all the users in a single file, and then parse the info.
Is there a better way to get that information instead of calling **Get-AdminPowerAppsUserDetails** for every user and get those huge amount of files?

Comment: Just as you would with any other cmdlet to get user information. Pass in a list of user names either dynamically from AD directly or via a text file you create frist. This is basic looping.

Comment: Not really. The command forces you to generate one different file for user. It is the only way it works. I want to avoid that.